# How can I use mp3/ogg sound files and png/jpeg images in the inject script of a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am having difficulty setting up sound files and image files in the inject script of my chrome extension. I have tried several solutions, and I have not figured out which method is the correct one. Can someone point me in the right direction for setting up the manifest file and which method to use for both sound files and image files. I believe I need to reference the specific file types in web-accessible-resources, and perhaps also the path to the images and sound files themselves? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this sample, png and mp3 are placed in the same folder as manifest.json.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "*.png",
        "*.mp3"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

matches.js

```js
const img = document.createElement("img");
const png = chrome.runtime.getURL("hoge.png");

img.src = png;

document.body.insertBefore(img, document.body.firstElementChild);

const audio = document.createElement("audio");
const mp3 = chrome.runtime.getURL("hoge.mp3");

audio.src = mp3;
audio.controls = true;

document.body.insertBefore(audio, document.body.firstElementChild);
```